# Refactoring objects using Laravel Collections fails

Tags: php, laravel, collections, higher-order-functions

What I try to do is that I need to return an array with key-value pairs from an array of objects.

From an api I get objects that looks something like this.

```
array:8 [▼
  0 => TargetingSearch {#229 ▼
    #data: array:6 [▼
      "id" => "6005609368513"
      "name" => "Software"
      "audience_size" => 565991450
      "path" => array:4 [▶]
      "description" => ""
      "topic" => "Technology"
    ]
    #_type_checker: TypeChecker {#228 ▶}
  }
```

The simple way to do it is to loop through the objects and push the values into an array.

```
  $codes = [];
  foreach($objects as $object) {
      $codes[] = [
        'id' => $object->id,
        'name' => $object->name,
      ];
  }
```

Which will return this that is exactly what I need.

```
['id' => 321, 'name' => "item1"],
['id' => 321, 'name' => "item1"],
['id' => 321, 'name' => "item1"],
```

I think that this is a little hard to manage and what I try to do is something a little more readable.

For example, by using the Laravel collection classes I could do something like this.

```
$codes = collect($objects)->pluck('id', 'name')->toArray();
```

The problem here is that this does not return the keys.

```
["item1" => "123"],
["item2" => "321"],
["item3" => "213"],
```

If I use

```
$codes = collect($objects)->only('id', 'name')->toArray();
```

It returns an empty array because the object itself is messing it all up.

anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "map" method

```
collect($objects)->map(function ($item) {
        return [
            'id'   => $item->id,
            'name' => $item->name
        ];
});
```